# Import private key from windows key store to make openssl connection

Tags: c, openssl

My current program(on windows) loads private key from a text file using SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file and creates SSL connection to server. 
Now I need to take the private key from windows certificate store.
OpenSSL don't seem to access windows cert store directly, please let me know how to do that?

Comment: Have you looked at the CAPI Engine?

Comment: Thanks,seems useful, I am checking that